# qplot no lazy evaluation of x and y

Tags: r, ggplot2, lazy-evaluation, r-grid

Take this example:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

data(diamonds)
name <- c("x","y","z")
l <- list()
j <- 1

for (i in 1:(length(name)-1)){
  for (k in (i+1):length(name)){
    l[[j]] <- qplot(diamonds[,name[i]], diamonds[,name[k]]) + 
      labs(x = name[i], y = name[k])
    j <- j + 1
  }
}

do.call(grid.arrange, l)
```

It prints 3 times the same plot:
[image]

I think this is because `qplot` does not evaluate *x* and *y* right away:

```
> l[[1]]$mapping
List of 2
 $ x: language diamonds[, name[i]]
 $ y: language diamonds[, name[k]]
```

So how do i make it evaluate `name[i]` right away?

**A workaround would be:**

```
for (i in 1:(length(name)-1)){
  for (k in (i+1):length(name)){
    l[[j]] <- ggplot(diamonds, aes_string(x=name[i], y=name[k])) +
      geom_point()
    j <- j + 1
  }
}
```

But then the full data-set is saved in the list-elements:

```
> str(l[[1]]$data)
'data.frame':   53940 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ carat  : num  0.23 0.21 0.23 0.29 0.31 0.24 0.24 0.26 0.22 0.23 ...
 $ cut    : Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "Fair"<"Good"<..: 5 4 2 4 2 3 3 3 1 3 ...
 $ color  : Ord.factor w/ 7 levels "D"<"E"<"F"<"G"<..: 2 2 2 6 7 7 6 5 2 5 ...
 $ clarity: Ord.factor w/ 8 levels "I1"<"SI2"<"SI1"<..: 2 3 5 4 2 6 7 3 4 5 ...
 $ depth  : num  61.5 59.8 56.9 62.4 63.3 62.8 62.3 61.9 65.1 59.4 ...
 $ table  : num  55 61 65 58 58 57 57 55 61 61 ...
 $ price  : int  326 326 327 334 335 336 336 337 337 338 ...
 $ x      : num  3.95 3.89 4.05 4.2 4.34 3.94 3.95 4.07 3.87 4 ...
 $ y      : num  3.98 3.84 4.07 4.23 4.35 3.96 3.98 4.11 3.78 4.05 ...
 $ z      : num  2.43 2.31 2.31 2.63 2.75 2.48 2.47 2.53 2.49 2.39 ...
```

Comment: The contents of `l[1]` and `l[2]` **are** different, as can be seen by looking at them or plotting them independently.  It's something about what your `do.call(grid.arrange,l)` is doing.  I haven't figured that part out yet.

Comment: The documentation on `arrangeGrob` is less than helpful, but if I write explicitly `grid.arrange(l[[1],l[[2]]) the wrong data are plotted, suggesting that more parameters need to be fed to the function.  Probably best to use plotting tools from the `ggplot2` or `grid` packages, which are better known and understood.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft `print(l[[1]])` and `print(l[[2]])` produce the same plot; as far as I can tell this has nothing to do with grid.arrange

Comment: @baptiste  I ran  `do.call(grid.arrange,l[1])` and similar for `l[2]` (notice the lack of double-brackets) and got different plots.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I'm guessing you ran this after the second piece of code ("workaround"), which does work as intended whichever way you use to print the plots.

Comment: @baptiste no, I just ran `l[[j]] <- qplot(diamonds[,name[i]], diamonds[,name[k]]) + 
+       labs(x = name[i], y = name[k])`  without a loop, just setting the `i,j,k` to fixed values.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft you got rid of the loop, and lazy evaluation was no longer a problem. I don't see how that helps with the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "workaround" is the correct way in my opinion. `qplot` is a convenience function, which I find completely unnecessary and never use. However, the problem is related to `qplot` creating a data.frame if you don't provide one and you can use it with a workaround like this:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

data(diamonds)
name <- c("x","y","z")
l <- list()
j <- 1

for (i in 1:(length(name)-1)){
  for (k in (i+1):length(name)){
    l[[j]] <- qplot(x, y, data = data.frame(x = diamonds[,name[i]], 
                                            y = diamonds[,name[k]])) + 
      labs(x = name[i], y = name[k])
    j <- j + 1
  }
}

do.call(grid.arrange, l)
```

[image]